# Aligning floats with two decimals by the point

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgfloat

I have a bunch of `UILabels` inside a vertical `UIStackView`. The stack is making all labels with the same width and height.

Each label has a float in it, like this:

[image]

But this is ugly aesthetically. I want to align the numbers by the point. Like this:

[image]

One of my problem is that these floats are in different labels.

These numbers use this to format:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", value];
```

I don't have a clue if even it is possible. So, I have no code to show. Is it possible to do that? How?

EDIT: The floats are left aligned on the labels. Ok, I can reduce the labels width and align them to the right, but I am wondering if there is another solution in code because reducing the labels's width will cause other problems on the interface, crapping the whole thing.

Comment: Yes I know. I added that to the question at the same time you were typing it...  I am wondering if there is a solution in code because doing that will crap the whole interface.

Comment: sorry about that!

Comment: Use NSTextAlignmentRight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If, as your edit says, you don't want to set your labels' `textAlignment` to right (which is certainly the easiest solution), here's another solution. You need to do two things:

1. You need to use a font with monospaced digits. In iOS 9 and later, the system font does **not** use monospaced digits by default, but there are programmatic ways to get a variant of the system font that does use monospaced digits. You can use [`+[UIFont monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:weight:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uifont/1619022-monospaceddigitsystemfontofsize), or if you already have a `UIFont` object, you can get a monospaced-digits variant (if there is one) by adding an attribute to its font descriptor. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30981587/77567) for code to do this (in Swift). Unfortunately there is no way to do this in a storyboard or xib without code.
2. You need to add enough [U+2007 FIGURE SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2007/index.htm)s to the beginning of each label's text to make them all the same length. For example, if they should all be five characters long:

   ```
   NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%.2f", value];
   while (text.length < 5) {
       text = [@"\u2007" stringByAppendingString:text];
   }
   label.text = text;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to set the `UILabel` to right align, e.g. Something like:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
```

Or for the single digit before the point case you could prepend the Unicode FIGURE SPACE, U+2007, this is a space with the same width as a digit in fonts with equal width digits and so all numbers will be the same width.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do that from code without reducing UILabel's width, you can subclass UILabel and override this method:

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = {0, 0, 0, rightOffset};
    [super drawTextInRect:UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets)];
}
```

Of course you should use right alignment as well.

Comment: I think this will do the trick! THANKS!